# Table of contents without \section, \chapter, etc commands

Tags: table-of-contents, bookmarks

I was wondering if it is possible to get a list of the bookmark from this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\mytitle[3]{\begin{tikzpicture} \node[ fill=red!80!white, minimum size=1cm]{#2\pdfbookmark[#3]{#2}{#1}};\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\mytitle{labtwo}{lev zero}{0} 
\blindtext
\mytitle{labone}{lev one}{1}
\blindtext
\mytitle{labtwo}{lev two}{2}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

without using \section, \chapter, etc commands.

Comment: Did you check the `.out` file created during the compilation? `\BOOKMARK [0][-]{labtwo.0}{lev zero}{}% 1
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{labone.1}{lev one}{labtwo.0}% 2
\BOOKMARK [2][-]{labtwo.2}{lev two}{labone.1}% 3`

Comment: Also, you can use `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}` inside your command to insert `#2` in the table of contents.

Comment: Don't use ``\\`` to terminate paragraphs.

Comment: @Sigur But in this way the level (#3) is missing...

Comment: @AriannaAngeletti, well I confess that I didn't understand what you want. Do you want a kind of table of contents but instead of the section names you want the labels with corresponding pages?

Comment: @Sigur I'd like to get a table of contents (by using \mytitle{#1}{#2}{#3}) with:
#2-->title
#3-->level

and corresponding pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many, many ways to get a table of contents and bookmarks without using `\section`, `\subsection` and similar commands.

The following example defines macros `\bkmlevel<roman level>` that map the level number to a sectioning level. Then `\addcontentsline` can be used that also creates the bookmark.

Also the code puts the anchor for the bookmark at the upper left corner of the node, created by `\mytitle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mytitle[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
      fill=red!80!white,
      minimum size=1cm,
      name={#1-#3},
    ]{%
      #2%
      \def\@currentHref{#1.#3}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{\@nameuse{bkmlevel\romannumeral#3}}{#2}%
    };
    \node[
      inner sep=0pt,
    ] at (#1-#3.north west) {\hypertarget{#1.#3}{}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand*{\bkmlevel}{section}
\newcommand*{\bkmleveli}{subsection}
\newcommand*{\bkmlevelii}{subsubsection}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \mytitle{labtwo}{lev zero}{0}
  \blindtext
  \mytitle{labone}{lev one}{1}
  \blindtext
  \mytitle{labtwo}{lev two}{2}
  \blindtext
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]